# SQL Select XML Node from XML

Tags: sql, xml

Could anyone advise the syntax to select an XML node from XML; assumind the following XML

```
<DOCUMENT>
  <CLIENT_DETAILS>
     ...more xml
  </CLIENT_DETAILS>
  <USER_DETAILS>
     ...more xml
  </USER_DETAILS>
<DOCUMENT>
```

SELECT @userDetails = *syntax*?
SELECT @clientDetails = *syntax*?

So that @userDatails would end up containing the following XML

```
<USER_DETAILS>
  ...more xml
</USER_DETAILS>
```

And @clientDetails would contain

```
<CLIENT_DETAILS>
   ...more xml
</CLIENT_DETAILS>
```

Comment: SQL = query language - that doesn't tell us what **database** you're using, and that information would be **vital** in order to answer this question. Please update your tags with the appropriate **database tag** - whether that's MySQL, IBM DB2, Oracle, SQL Server, Sybase, Interbase, Postgres - or whatever else you might be using

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be much simpler than expected

SELECT @userDetails = @mainXML.query('DOCUMENT/USER_DETAILS');